# SSL connect error when installing sas7bdat.parso library

Tags: ssl, error-handling, sas

I'm trying to read massive sas7bdat databases (over 250 million entries) in R and I've trying to install the parso library several times, however, every time this error shows up:

devtools::install_github("BioStatMatt/sas7bdat.parso")
Error in curl::curl_fetch_disk(url, x$path, handle = handle) : 
  SSL connect error

I've already installed rjava and devtools packages without errors, also, I'm running on the latest version of R Studio, and I've already tried using the read.sas7bdat (for non compressed databases) and re-installing xml, curl, Rcurl and httr libraries, but the error persists.

I'm not that good with R and I'm afraid I'm having lots of trouble trying to fix this issue by reading similar posts.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.